# Columns Named as Numbers

Tags: r, subset, names

I have a data frame that already has columns named by numbers:

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   8305 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ 1 : num  0.652 0.526 0.504 0.628 0.744 ...
 $ 2 : num  0.498 0.476 0.454 0.454 0.498 ...
 $ 3 : num  0.3537 0.0368 0.3421 0.3421 0.3537 ...
 $ 4 : num  0.298 0.031 0.309 0.305 0.313 ...
 $ 5 : num  0.2808 0.0292 0.2781 0.2811 0.2808 ...
```

I know that a command such as `df$1` or `df$as.character(1)` do not work, but is there a way to subset without using index numbers (so NO `df[,1]`)?

Answer (score 3):

You can do

```
df$`1`
```

Any name that cannot be treated as an R variable needs to be wrapped with backticks. Of course you could also just do

```
df["1"]
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use quotes in the case of `[` and backticks in the case of `$`.

```
> x <- data.frame(`2`=1, `1`=2, check.names=FALSE)
> x
  2 1
1 1 2
> x[,"2"]
[1] 1
> x$`2`
[1] 1
> x$`1`
[1] 2
> x[,"1"]
[1] 2
```

Comment: You can also use quotes with `$`: `x$'1' #[1] 2`

Comment: @BondedDust: yeah, but that feels dirty, because the value is supposed to be a name/symbol not a character string.

Comment: Well, it's supposed to equivalent to `x[[as.character(1)]]`.

Comment: @BondedDust: Hmm, not sure where I got the impression that it was "supposed to be". "Can be" would be more appropriate. And technically, it's supposed to be equivalent to `x[["1", exact=FALSE]]` (i.e., `$` allows partial matching).

Comment: Right. Another potential `$`-gotcha.